# Python - indexing for different elements in file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, element

I have a sample inputfile.txt:

```
chr15   74436458    74466677    pi-1700016M24Rik.1  -
chr17   79734018    79754230    pi-Cdc42ep3.1   -
chr3    124103907   124128909   pi-1700006A11Rik.1  -
chr5    102261978   102280532   pi-Wdfy3.1  -
chr6    85061409    85076088    pi-Gm5878.1 -
chr9    51573456    51661164    pi-Arhgap20.1   +
chr10   127114107   127132221   pi-Tmem194.1    +
chr11   103286577   103315010   11-qE1-9443.1   +
chr11   107855325   107859037   11-qE1-3997.1   +
chr11   108278889   108286739   11-qE1-252.1    -
chr12   99620581    99658258    12-qE-23911.1   -
chr12   99658453    99692927    12-qE-7089.1    +
chr13   21595489    21598393    13-qA3.1-213.1  -
chr13   24997468    25026901    13-qA3.1-355.1  +
```

Column1=chromosome_number

Column2=start

Column3=end

Column4=gene_name

Column5=Orientation (either + or -)

1.) I need to extract lines that have the same chromosome number, their start sites have a difference of 200 that are in **opposite** orientation (one is plus/minus).

I am stumbled how to approach it. I have this so far where I made two lists of start sites (one for plus orientation and one for minus). But not sure how I can do this with python. Any advice will be much appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import csv

f=open('Samplefileinput.txt', 'r')

list1=[] #start sites with + direction
list2=[] #start sites with - direction
for line in f:
  fields=line.strip().split()
  chromosome =fields[0]
  start=int(fields[1])
  end=int(fields[2])
  gene=fields[3]
  direction = fields[4] #plus/minus
  if '+' in direction:
     list1.append(start)
  if '-' in direction:
     list2.append(start)
```

But this doesnt help me at all. stumbled as to how I can continue. Many thanks.

```
Ideal Output:

  ChrX   start_number1            gene_name1
  ChrX   start_number1+/-200      gene_name2
  ChrY   start_number2            gene_name3
  ChrZ   start_number2+/-200      gene_name4
```

Where the first two reads will be in different orientations. 
Also the same case for last two.

I am not sure how many lines of output there will be. Thanks so much!

Comment: What do you want your lists to contain? something like every line with chr11 in the first column? can you give an ideal output?

Comment: @user1862770 I edited the question. Sorry for the confusion. Hope its more clear

Comment: I would think some like: (1) sort the data based on chromosome number, (2) sort each subset based on their start number, calculate deltas until they exceed 200, and on what's left pick the ones that satisfy the +/- requirement. In terms of python code, I'd use a dictionary where the key is the chr-num and value would be a list of tuples (start_num, sign), on which you'd have to perform those distance calculations. there's probably some module apt for these sort of things, but wouldn't be hard to do manually.

Comment: What sal says sounds fine to me, he was faster

Comment: But I would probably first remove the "Chr" from the first column, then you can really order by the first column as you would then have only numbers in column one. After that, proceed as sal says.

Comment: @sal & user1862770 thanks, guy! I am working on the script now. Will let you know once i get something

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want to duplicate genes that meet the requirement with multiple other genes. The itertools module is really amazing for these types of grouping and permuting operations:

```
import itertools as it

def getrecords(f):
    for line in open(f):
        yield line.strip().split()

key = lambda x: x[0]
for i,rec in it.groupby(sorted(getrecords('inputfile.txt'), key=key), key=key):
    for c0,c1 in it.combinations(rec, 2): 
        if (c0[4] != c1[4]) and (abs(int(c0[1])-int(c1[1])) > 200):
            print '%s\t%s\t%s' % (c0[0], c0[1], c0[3])
            print '%s\t%s\t%s' % (c1[0], c1[1], c1[3])
```

Output:

```
chr11   103286577   11-qE1-9443.1
chr11   108278889   11-qE1-252.1
chr11   107855325   11-qE1-3997.1
chr11   108278889   11-qE1-252.1
chr12   99620581    12-qE-23911.1
chr12   99658453    12-qE-7089.1
chr13   21595489    13-qA3.1-213.1
chr13   24997468    13-qA3.1-355.1
```

Comment: Very cool solution. After reading carefully the question again, I think that the check against the value 200 is an equality check.

Comment: yes, it has to be an equality check :) thank you @fivetentaylor. so much! will try it on my own and see if i get a solution. If not, will go with this one :)!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run through each list and pull out the matches, but I think you want to pull through the other attributes into your lists so you can match on them.

```
if '+' in direction:
   list1.append(fields)
if '-' in direction:
   list2.append(fields)
```

From here you can check for matches.

```
matchlist=[]
for pos in list1:
  for neg in list2:
    if pos[0]==neg[0] and abs(pos[1]-neg[1])==200:
      matchlist.append([pos[3], neg[3]])
```

This should work to create a list of matches for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Chr from every item in the first column
(you can go through every line and only keep

```
  [3:]
```

of each line, means everything but the first 3 chars. 
Then sort the lines by the first column and you should almost be finished?